# Why do I need extraneous braces for the label in an arrow?

Tags: tikz-cd

I was getting scope errors on a commutative diagram, and adding {} inside the quote marks eliminated the error. Why and under what circumstances are they needed.

This fails:

```
 \ar[d, "\operatorname{g}_{\sigma_\beta}, \beta \prec \Beta_\gamma"]
```

This works:

```
 \ar[d, "{\operatorname{g}_{\sigma_\beta}, \beta \prec \Beta_\gamma}"]
```

Comment: Don't use `\operatorname` as a substitute for `\mathrm`. Not the first time I tell you. :)

Comment: The problem is the comma. TikZ splits the argument at commas, so it becomes confused when the comma in the label is found. Adding a pair of braces is a safe workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options in the argument to `\ar` (I'd prefer using `\arrow`, but it's just me) are split at commas and then evaluated. The comma in the label thus confuses the parser, because it finds the unfinished option

```
"\operatorname{g}_{\sigma\beta}
```

The braces are thus necessary for getting the parser right.

*Please*, don't use `\operatorname` as a substitute for `\mathrm`:

```
\ar[d, "{\mathrm{g}_{\sigma_\beta}, \beta \prec \Beta_\gamma}"]
```

is the right input.

Comment: To clarify for @egreg, I have a sequence of functions and want to mark up name_subsript to indicate that it is a function. What I'm currently doing is to define a \funcname command that expands to \mathrm(#1), and marking up the text as \funcname(name)_subscript.

Comment: If someone needs the true source for the quoted-string-shenanigans, please check that [tikz-cd-manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) chapter 1.2, which in turn directs you to the [pgf manual](http://saimei.ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) chapter 17.10.4.