# Typing ordered pairs over arrows in a tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

When I try to type an ordered pair like `(x,y)` over an arrow in a tikz-cd I get the following error message:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

The code that works looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
            A\arrow[r, ""]\arrow[d, ""] &   B\arrow[d, ""]\\\
            C\arrow[r, ""]              &   D.
\end{tikzcd}
```

The code that doesn't work looks like this

```
\begin{tikzcd}
            A\arrow[r, "(x,y)"]\arrow[d, ""]    &   B\arrow[d, ""]\\\
            C\arrow[r, ""]                      &   D.
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the text to be set over/under the arrow has a comma, it must be braced: `\arrow[r,"{(x,y)}"]` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321804/why-do-i-need-extraneous-braces-for-the-label-in-an-arrow

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you show us what you're trying to achieve?